# why it is better to rebase instead of merge to resolve the conflicts for the maintainer?

Tags: git

I'm reading the Pro Git book and got confused by rebasing to resolve the conflicts for the maintainer. The first picture below is the starting point:

[image]

And the author says:

**Let’s say the project maintainer has pulled in a bunch of other patches and tried your first branch, but it no longer cleanly merges. In this case, you can try to rebase that branch on top of origin/master, resolve the conflicts for the maintainer, and then resubmit your changes:**

```
$ git checkout featureA
$ git rebase origin/master
$ git push -f myfork featureA
```

**This rewrites your history to now look like Commit history after featureA work..**
[image]

I'm confused, what does "but it no longer cleanly merges" mean and why I need to to rebase that branch on top of origin/master, resolve the conflicts for the maintainer? I mean if the maintainer likes my `featureA`, he/she can just merge my branch to the local master branch(origin/master on my end), what's the problem with that?

Comment: The scenario the book is talking about is called a "merge conflict"; search for that term, and the rest of it will probably start making sense.

Comment: Not sure if i understood the context correctly, but i think it's because the featureA branch is not updated with master branch, so it would push not updated changes, this can (or not) make conflicts. It's better to update your branch, merge by yourself and then push everything correctly updated for review.

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea is that you take responsibility for the changes made in your own feature. If other changes have been pulled before yours, and some of them overlap (i.e. conflict) with changes you have made, then *someone* has to go through and resolve the conflicts so the merge can be completed.

On the one hand, you could argue that if the maintainer likes your feature and wants it, they should be prepared to do this bit of work to get it (i.e. they resolve conflicts when they pull your change). On the other hand, maintainers are generally very pressed for time and it is kinder to the maintainer that you do this yourself (i.e. you rebase, resolve conflicts at that point, then make a "clean" pull request). Practically speaking, it's probably easier for you to appropriately resolve the conflicts, as you wrote the code for the feature so understand it better.

tl;dr let's try to minimise work for project maintainters!

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I got it!   Could you also have a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58119163/why-need-a-second-tracking-branch-for-origin-master/58119226?noredirect=1#comment102627997_58119226

Answer (score 0):

> he/she can just merge my branch to the local master branch(origin/master on my end)

If the branches have diverged, whether the merge is easy depends on what exactly has been 
changed in both branches.

If they have not diverged, merging is trivial (then they can *just* be merged). You can create this situation by first rebasing your branch on the remote branch.

Effectively, if there are conflicts, you have to resolve them when rebasing, instead of postponing it to when the merge is made.